# get_the_category_list to display only two categories

Tags: wordpress

I am using get_the_category_list()  function for getting categories but for a particular post if there is too many categories it looks bad.

I want to display just 2 or 3 categories not all.

How can I achieve this using get_the_category_list()  function

Answer (score 0):

Get the categories into a variable:

```
$categories_list = get_the_category_list();
```

Now you can get the number of elements you want using array_slice.

```
$output = array_slice($categories_list, 2);
```

Next display  $output in the way you want and you will get only 2 categories displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many methods. if you want 2, then you can simply use index.

first category $categories_list[0];
second category $categories_list[1];

you can also add (isset($categories_list[1]))  to avoid undefined index errors.